# TeX does not show bibliography in pdf file

Tags: bibliographies, errors

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

fsdkjjfashgjfang jdfshlkj \cite{bar}

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

I have `biblio.bib` file in the same TeX folder.

Inside `biblio.bib` file,

```
@BOOK{bar,
        AUTHOR = "Star, R. M.",
        TITLE = "Foo Bar Baz",
        PUBLISHER = {MIT Press},
        ADDRESS = {Cambridge, MA},
        YEAR = 1989}.
```

I  tried every solution available in the net but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex > bibtex > (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: yes i did but when i ran bibtex it says ''need exactly one file argument'' process exited normally. still not seen bibliography

Comment: Do you have a `.bbl` file? Also, which editor do you use?

Comment: No i don't have .bbl file. I am using Tex editor.

Comment: Which editor? Maybe it's misconfigured

Comment: There should definitely be no `.` ("dot") at the end of the entry in the bib file.

Comment: As the `plain` bibliography style can only generate numeric citation call-outs, you should load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`. Then, re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propage all changes.

Comment: No it did not work. still could not see bibliography.

Comment: I tried it with your example and it worked in my editor...

May you enter `\appendix` before your `\bibliographystyle` ?

Comment: I am using .tex editor .i tried with \appendix and without \appendix. but not working in both cases.

Comment: My bibliography system also removes the `.` as mentioned by Mico above. Do you have dots in your `.bib` file?

Comment: my filename is only biblio but exactly it is biblio.bib

Comment: could you show me how to remove ''.'' from .bib file?

Comment: `@BOOK{bar,
        AUTHOR = "Star, R. M.",
        TITLE = "Foo Bar Baz",
        PUBLISHER = {MIT Press},
        ADDRESS = {Cambridge, MA},
        YEAR = 1989}**.** `

Comment: I mean the dot with the stars surrounded

Comment: i removed it still could not see bibliograph. but got  [?] at the place of cite.

Comment: okay, then try again with `pdflatex>bibtex>pdflatex>pdflatex`

Comment: when i ran bibtex  i got ''need exactly one file argument process exited normally'',,it might be the problem to create bibliograph

Comment: Okay, then creating a new bibliography may would help? What reference manager do you use? I would recommend zotero or jabref

Comment: Inside my latex folder there is bibtex folder.inside bibtex there is bib folder .inside bib there is base folder.inside base there is test.bib file  with many references,so i have used that one and changed biblio instead of test thats it.i dont have idea about other references.

Comment: But your `.bib` file is directly in the same folder as your `.tex` file? If not, this is the error. It has to be directly in the same folder. Otherwise, you have to give the path of the file!

Comment: yes it is in the same folder as my .tex file.

Comment: Okay, then I don't know where the error lies. As I said: it worked when I tried...

Comment: but it didnt work in my computer

Comment: my references worked when i tried bimtex but did not work in bibtex.its strange

Comment: 0
down vote
 

I copied your text file as listed into gvim and saved as test_bib.tex. I copied the biblio.bib without the last fullstop into gvim and saved. I then ran pdflatex test_bib.tex, bibtex test_bib.aux, pdflatex test_bib.tex, pdflatex test_bib.tex, and viewed the test_bib.pdf - worked 100%

Comment: Please tell us how exactly you run bibtex.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39574/discussion-on-question-by-punam-sharma-tex-does-not-show-bibliography-in-pdf-fil).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your bib file causing your problem.

First a remark: it is better to use `{...}` than `"..."`. I changed it in my following MWE.

Please see the follwing bib file:

```
@BOOK{bar,
  AUTHOR    = {Star, R. M.},
  TITLE     = {Foo Bar Baz},
  PUBLISHER = {MIT Press},
  ADDRESS   = {Cambridge, MA},
  YEAR      = {1989},           <======================
}                               <======================
```

Your errors are:

- you did not end the entry for `bar` with an closing `}`
- you ended the value for field `year` with `}`, but you didn't start it with `{`
- end each field entry with an comma. Your shown `.` is syntactical wrong.

So please run the following complete MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and TeX code in one compilable MWE!):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{bar,
  AUTHOR    = {Star, R. M.},
  TITLE     = {Foo Bar Baz},
  PUBLISHER = {MIT Press},
  ADDRESS   = {Cambridge, MA},
  YEAR      = {1989}, 
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
fsdkjjfashgjfang jdfshlkj \cite{bar}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{\jobname} %      to use bib file created with filecontents
\end{document}
```

and see the result:

[image: resulting bibliography]